# Python struct calsize different from actual

Tags: python, struct, padding, sizeof

I am trying to read one short and long from a binary file using python `struct`.

But the

```
print(struct.calcsize("hl")) # o/p 16
```

which is wrong, It should have been 2 bytes for short and 8 bytes for long. I am not sure i am using the `struct` module the wrong way.

When i print the value for each it is

```
print(struct.calcsize("h")) # o/p 2
print(struct.calcsize("l")) # o/p 8
```

Is there a way to force python to maintain the precision on `datatypes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default struct alignment rules, 16 is the correct answer. Each field is aligned to match its size, so you end up with a `short` for two bytes, then six bytes of padding (to reach the next address aligned to a multiple of eight bytes), then eight bytes for the `long`.

You can use a [byte order prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) (any of them disable padding), but they *also* disable machine native sizes (so `struct.calcsize("=l")` will be a fixed 4 bytes on all systems, and `struct.calcsize("=hl")` will be 6 bytes on all systems, not 10, even on systems with 8 byte `long`s).

If you want to compute struct sizes for arbitrary structures using machine native types with non-default padding rules, you'll need to go to the `ctypes` module, define your [`ctypes.Structure`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure) subclass with the desired `_pack_` setting, then use [`ctypes.sizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof) to check the size, e.g.:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_long, c_short, sizeof

class HL(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1  # Disables padding for field alignment
    # Defines (unnamed) fields, a short followed by long
    _fields_ = [("", c_short),
               ("", c_long)]

print(sizeof(HL))
```

which outputs `10` as desired.

This could be factored out as a utility function if needed (this is a simplified example that doesn't handle all `struct` format codes, but you can expand if needed):

```
from ctypes import *

FMT_TO_TYPE = dict(zip("cb?hHiIlLqQnNfd",
                       (c_char, c_byte, c_bool, c_short, c_ushort, c_int, c_uint,
                        c_long, c_ulong, c_longlong, c_ulonglong, 
                        c_ssize_t, c_size_t, c_float, c_double)))

def calcsize(fmt, pack=None):
    '''Compute size of a format string with arbitrary padding (defaults to native)'''
    class _(Structure):
        if pack is not None:
            _pack_ = pack
        _fields_ = [("", FMT_TO_TYPE[c]) for c in fmt]
    return sizeof(_)
```

which, once defined, lets you compute sizes padded or unpadded like so:

```
>>> calcsize("hl")     # Defaults to native "natural" alignment padding
16
>>> calcsize("hl", 1)  # pack=1 means no alignment padding between members
10
```

Comment: I am not sure why, the output for me is 0. https://repl.it/repls/TenseWhirlwindIbadanmalimbe

Comment: @IvinPoloSony: It was a typo in my original post (now fixed). I'm testing on one machine, hand-jamming it over to this machine (which lacks Python). Meant to type `_fields_`, typoed it as `_field_` (which is not a special attribute, so the structure ended up with no fields at all). [It's now fixed](https://tio.run/##TY@9isMwEIR7PcWQNBK4CekOrkuRIt2VIRhFP7Y4eSUkmeC8vE@2D5NttphvdmbjVPpA53m2KQxQZYomww0xpIKfkkZVxmQaqNYH6pad@yo1yO5tgmVMeZkzrje@w@KLoU4bpfpt8Y0TcMTFZfn09XSUWjvqYEOCdcZrSO86GgyV1VZRYx1Vko9EcjBabFxuILGGV6/34WU0nhOWWlveRi2Jd3447FVFs8qf8y8vVvFgLCZHhW8P8etNiHn@Aw).

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) says:

> By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad bytes, use `standard` size and alignment instead of `native` size and alignment

Changing it from standard to native is pretty easy: you just append the prefix `=` before the format characters.

```
print(struct.calcsize("=hl"))
```

---

EDIT

Since from the native to standard mode, some default sizes are changed, you have two options:

- keeping the native mode, but switching the format characters, in this way: `struct.calcsize("lh")`. In C even the order of your variable inside the struct is important. Here the padding is 8 bytes, it means that every variable has to be referenced at multiple of 8 bytes.
- Using the format characters of the standard mode, so: `struct.calcsize("=hq")`

Comment: As I noted in my answer, the problem here is that any of those prefixes not only disable padding, but switch from native size/alignment to "standard" size/alignment. So `struct.calcsize("hl")` on a system with 64 bit `long`s reports 16 (2 bytes for `short`, 6 pad bytes, 8 bytes for `long`), but moving to `struct.calcsize("=hl")` doesn't get you 10, it gets you 6, because it not only removed the pad bytes, it also "standardized" the size of a `long` to 4.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right. I made some tests and I noticed it too. In that case he can use the `q` prefix